# Error while reading the file in SharePoint Document Library

Tags: development, csom

I have developed C# console application using csom to read all the files (excel, doc, slide, pdf) in the SharePoint Document Library and converts to memory stream and retrieved if any external links are used in the files. The application is working as expected when tested in my local machine

When I deploy the code to the server and tested another site "http://edms.com.sg:2100/sites/FD/EDMS", I am getting the below error:

> "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   The property or field 'Length' has not been initialised. It has not
>   been requested or the request ha not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested."

[image]

Below is function code

```
namespace ExScan_EDMS
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string siteUrl = "";
        public static string _logFileName = "";
        public static DateTime _startTime, _endTime;
        public static uint _totalFileCounter = 0;
        public static uint _totalFileWithLinks = 0;
        public static uint _totalFileWithPassword = 0;
        public static bool _promptForPassword = false;
        public static string _ignorePathContaining = "~snapshot";
        public static string ReplaceKeyWord1 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReplaceKeyWord1"].ToString();
        public static string ReplaceKeyWord2 = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReplaceKeyWord2"].ToString();
        public static string _title = "";
        public static List<string> subfolderslst;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            String FullURL = "";

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
            string displayName = String.Format("|    ExScan_EDMS - Office File Scanner - {0}   |", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
            Console.WriteLine(new String('=', displayName.Length));
            Console.WriteLine(displayName);
            Console.WriteLine(new String('=', displayName.Length));
            Console.ResetColor();

            try
            {
               FullURL = args[0];
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please specify path: \r\n e.g. ExScan.exe \"site url\"");
                return;
            }

            List<string> siteList = GetSitesFromURL(FullURL); //try to get the sharepoint site

            if (siteList.Any())
            {
                siteUrl = siteList[siteList.Count() - 1]; //get the last url as the site
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to find a valid site URL");
            }

            _startTime = DateTime.Now;

            _logFileName = String.Format("log_{0}.csv", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss"));

            Console.WriteLine("main url {0}", siteUrl);
            using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
            {
                Log.WriteHeader();

                string path = string.Empty;
                path = FullURL.Replace(siteUrl, "").Trim();

                String[] folderdetails = path.Split('/');

                int cnt = 0;
                subfolderslst = new List<string>();
                foreach (string s in folderdetails)
                {
                    cnt++;
                    if (cnt == 1)
                        _title = s.ToString().Trim();
                    if (cnt > 1)
                        subfolderslst.Add(s.ToString().Trim());
                }

                clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
                clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(_title);
                //var rootFolder = list.RootFolder;

                clientContext.Load(web, website => website.Title, website => website.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, w => w.Lists, w => w.Title);
                clientContext.Load(list);

                if (subfolderslst.Count == 0)
                {
                    FolderCollection Mainfolderscol = list.RootFolder.Folders;

                    clientContext.Load(Mainfolderscol);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (Folder MainFolder in Mainfolderscol)
                    {
                        GetFoldersAndFiles(MainFolder, clientContext);
                    }
                }

                else if (subfolderslst.Count > 0)
                {
                    FolderCollection folderscol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
                    clientContext.Load(folderscol);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    String FolderName = string.Empty;
                    if (subfolderslst.Count == 1)
                    {
                        FolderName = subfolderslst[subfolderslst.Count - 1].ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FolderName = subfolderslst[subfolderslst.Count - 2].ToString();
                    }

                    foreach (Folder subFolder in folderscol)
                    {
                        if (subFolder.Name == FolderName)
                        {
                            if (subfolderslst.Count == 1)
                            {
                                if (subFolder.Name == subfolderslst[subfolderslst.Count - 1].ToString())
                                {
                                    GetFoldersAndFiles(subFolder, clientContext);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (subfolderslst.Count > 1)
                            {
                                FolderCollection folderscol1 = subFolder.ListItemAllFields.Folder.Folders;
                                clientContext.Load(folderscol1);
                                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                                foreach (Folder subFolder1 in folderscol1)
                                {
                                    if (subFolder1.Name == subfolderslst[subfolderslst.Count - 1].ToString())
                                    {
                                        GetFoldersAndFiles(subFolder1, clientContext);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            _endTime = DateTime.Now;
            string endResult = String.Format("\r\n\r\nSUMMARY:\r\nStart: {0}\r\nEnd: {1}\r\nTotal Files: {2}\r\nFiles with Links: {3}\r\nFiles with Passwords: {4}\r\nLog File: {5}", _startTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), _endTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"), _totalFileCounter.ToString(), _totalFileWithLinks.ToString(), _totalFileWithPassword.ToString(), _logFileName);
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine(endResult);
            Console.ResetColor();
            Log.WriteAnythingToLog(endResult);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }


        private static void GetFoldersAndFiles(Folder mainFolder, ClientContext clientContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("inside GetFoldersAndFiles method");
            clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
            clientContext.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            clientContext.Load(mainFolder, k => k.Files, k => k.Folders);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.WriteLine("after credentialss");

            foreach (var folder in mainFolder.Folders)
            {
                GetFoldersAndFiles(folder, clientContext);
            }

            foreach (var file in mainFolder.Files)
            {

                try
                {
                    var fileRef = file.ServerRelativeUrl;
                    var fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef);

                    var serverRelativeUrl = fileRef;


                    var fileurl = new Uri(clientContext.Url)
                      .GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + serverRelativeUrl;

                    using (var objMemory = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
                        int iRead = 0;

                        while ((iRead = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            objMemory.Write(buffer, 0, iRead);
                        }

                        objMemory.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        ProcessFile(objMemory, file.Name, fileurl, file.TimeCreated, file.TimeLastModified, file.Length, "");


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string e = ex.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine("inside objMemory err msg: {0}", e);

                    continue;

                }
            }
        }

        public static void ProcessFile(System.IO.MemoryStream objMemory, string fileName, string fileurl, DateTime fileTimeCreated, DateTime fileTimeLastModified, long fileLength, string WorkbookPassword = "")
        {

            //Set license
            Aspose.Cells.License license = new Aspose.Cells.License();
            license.SetLicense("Aspose.Total.lic");

            //Use when path is too long and file had to be copied locally to be analyzed
            string newLocalPath = String.Empty;
            string FileName = String.Empty;


            string extension = string.Empty;
            int fileExtPos = fileName.LastIndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            if (fileExtPos >= 0)
                extension = fileName.Substring(fileExtPos, fileName.Length - fileExtPos);

            LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
            FileName = fileName;

            if (FileName.Contains(ReplaceKeyWord1))
            {
                FileName = FileName.Replace(ReplaceKeyWord1, "");
            }
            else if (FileName.Contains(ReplaceKeyWord2))
            {
                FileName = FileName.Replace(ReplaceKeyWord2, "");
            }
            logEntry.Filename = FileName.Trim(); //Path.GetFileName(path);
            logEntry.Extension = extension;
            logEntry.Path = fileurl.Replace(FileName, "").Trim();
            logEntry.Created = fileTimeCreated;
            logEntry.Modified = fileTimeLastModified;
            logEntry.Accessed = fileTimeLastModified;
            logEntry.FileSize = fileLength;

            try
            {
                Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions options = new Aspose.Cells.LoadOptions();

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkbookPassword)) //load password
                {
                    options.Password = WorkbookPassword;
                    logEntry.HasPassword = true;
                    _totalFileWithPassword++;
                }

                if (extension != null && (extension.ToLower() == ".xls" || extension.ToLower() == ".xlsx" || extension.ToLower() == ".xlsm"))
                {
                    using (Workbook workbook = new Workbook(objMemory, options))
                    {
                        if (workbook.Settings.IsWriteProtected)
                        {
                        }

                        //Macro Handling
                        logEntry.HasMacro = workbook.HasMacro;
                        bool hasMacroButNoLinksInMacro = true;

                        if (logEntry.HasMacro)
                        {
                            VbaModuleCollection modules = workbook.VbaProject.Modules;

                            for (int i = 0; i < modules.Count; i++)
                            {
                                VbaModule module = modules[i];
                                //Console.WriteLine("Module: {0}", module.Name);
                                String code = module.Codes;
                                String pattern = @"(\w:\\[\w \\]+[.][\w]+)"; //match local path

                                foreach (var matchedPath in Regex.Matches(code, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    logEntry.MacroModule = module.Name;
                                    logEntry.MacroLinks = matchedPath.ToString();
                                    Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Module: {0} Local Path: {1}", module.Name, matchedPath.ToString());
                                    hasMacroButNoLinksInMacro = false;
                                }

                                pattern = @"([\\]{2}[\w \\]+[.][\w]+)"; //match network path

                                foreach (var matchedPath in Regex.Matches(code, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    logEntry.MacroModule = module.Name;
                                    logEntry.MacroLinks = matchedPath.ToString();
                                    Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Module: {0} Remote Path: {1}", module.Name, matchedPath.ToString());
                                    hasMacroButNoLinksInMacro = false;
                                }
                                //Replace the original message with the modified message
                                //if (code.Contains("This is test message."))
                                //{
                                //    code = code.Replace("This is test message.", "This is Aspose.Cells message.");
                                //    module.Codes = code;
                                //}
                            }
                        }

                        logEntry.MacroLinks = ""; //clear
                        logEntry.MacroModule = "";

                        if (workbook.HasExernalLinks()) //Process those with external links
                        {
                            //Increment File With Links Counter
                            _totalFileWithLinks++;

                            var links = workbook.Worksheets.ExternalLinks;

                            for (int i = 0; i < links.Count; i++)
                            {
                                logEntry.Links = links[i].DataSource;
                                logEntry.LinksReferred = links[i].IsReferred;
                                Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                            }

                        }
                        else //Process those without external inks
                        {
                            if (!logEntry.HasMacro)
                                Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                            else
                            {
                                //File has macro but no links were found
                                if (hasMacroButNoLinksInMacro)
                                {
                                    logEntry.MacroLinks = ""; //clear
                                    logEntry.MacroModule = "";
                                    Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //Increment Total File Counter
                    _totalFileCounter++;
                }
                else if (extension != null && (extension.ToLower() == ".doc" || extension.ToLower() == ".docx"))
                {
                    Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Aspose.Words.Document(objMemory);
                    uint _hlinkcnt = 0;
                    foreach (Aspose.Words.Fields.Field field in doc.Range.Fields)
                    {
                        if (field.Type == Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldType.FieldHyperlink)
                        {
                            FieldHyperlink link = (FieldHyperlink)field;
                            logEntry.Links = link.Address;
                            logEntry.LinksReferred = false;
                            Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                            _hlinkcnt++;
                        }
                    }

                    if (_hlinkcnt > 0)
                        _totalFileWithLinks++;
                    else
                        Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);

                    //Increment Total File Counter
                    _totalFileCounter++;
                }
                else if (extension != null && (extension.ToLower() == ".ppt" || extension.ToLower() == ".pptx"))
                {
                    Presentation pres = new Presentation(objMemory);
                    uint _hlinkcnt = 0;
                    //Get the hyperlinks from presentation slides
                    foreach (ISlide slide in pres.Slides)
                    {
                        IList<IHyperlinkContainer> links = slide.HyperlinkQueries.GetAnyHyperlinks();

                        if (links.Count > 0)
                            _hlinkcnt++;

                        foreach (IHyperlinkContainer link in links)
                        {
                            logEntry.Links = link.HyperlinkClick.ExternalUrl;
                            Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                        }
                    }

                    if (_hlinkcnt > 0)
                        _totalFileWithLinks++;
                    else
                        Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);

                    //Increment Total File Counter
                    _totalFileCounter++;
                }
                else if (extension != null && extension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
                {
                    //Open document
                    Aspose.Pdf.Document document = new Aspose.Pdf.Document(objMemory);

                    uint _hlinkcnt = 0;
                    // Traverse through all the page of PDF
                    foreach (Aspose.Pdf.Page page in document.Pages)
                    {
                        // Get the link annotations from particular page
                        Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Annotations.AnnotationSelector selector = new Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Annotations.AnnotationSelector(new Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Annotations.LinkAnnotation(page, Aspose.Pdf.Rectangle.Trivial));

                        page.Accept(selector);
                        // Create list holding all the links
                        System.Collections.IList list = selector.Selected;
                        // Iterate through invidiaul item inside list
                        foreach (Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.Annotations.LinkAnnotation a in list)
                        {
                            // Print the destination URL
                            _hlinkcnt++;
                            logEntry.Links = (a.Action as Aspose.Pdf.InteractiveFeatures.GoToURIAction).URI;
                            Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                        }
                    }

                    if (_hlinkcnt > 0)
                        _totalFileWithLinks++;
                    else
                        Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);

                    //Increment Total File Counter
                    _totalFileCounter++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Processed file {0}: '{1}'.", _totalFileCounter, fileurl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                //Process those with errors
                if (new Regex(@"Please\sprovide\spassword").IsMatch(e.Message) || e.Message.ToLower().Contains("password")) //Password required
                {
                    if (_promptForPassword) //if Y was set as 2nd input variable
                    {
                        SecureString password = PasswordServices.PromptPassword(fileurl);
                        //call to process the file again
                        /////ProcessFile(path, SecureClass.ToInsecureString(password));

                        //Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                        //Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", path);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        logEntry.Remarks += e.Message;
                        logEntry.HasPassword = true;
                        _totalFileWithPassword++;
                        Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);

                        //Increment Total File Counter
                        _totalFileCounter++;

                        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                        Console.WriteLine("Skipped passworded file {0}: '{1}'.", _totalFileCounter, fileurl);
                        Console.ResetColor();
                    }
                }
                else
                    if (new Regex(@"Invalid\spassword").IsMatch(e.Message)) //Password entered is invalid
                    {
                        if (_promptForPassword) //ask for password again
                        {
                            _totalFileWithPassword--; //deduct file count due to invalid password

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(WorkbookPassword))
                            {
                                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                                Console.WriteLine("Password is invalid");
                                Console.ResetColor();

                                SecureString password = PasswordServices.PromptPassword(fileurl);
                                //call to process the file again
                                ////ProcessFile(fileurl, SecureClass.ToInsecureString(password));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _totalFileCounter++;
                        logEntry.Remarks += e.Message;
                        Log.WriteToLog(logEntry);
                        Console.WriteLine("Processed file {0}: '{1}'.", _totalFileCounter, fileurl);
                    }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// GetSitesFromURL - Used to get the site uri
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="SiteURL"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static List<string> GetSitesFromURL(string SiteURL)
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(SiteURL);
            string strRootURL = String.Format("{0}://{1}", uri.Scheme, uri.Authority);
            string strBuildupPath = String.Empty;
            List<string> possibleSites = new List<string>();


            foreach (var s in uri.Segments)
            {
                try
                {
                    strBuildupPath += s;

                    string strSiteURL = String.Format("{0}{1}", strRootURL, strBuildupPath);

                    using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(strSiteURL))
                    {
                        Web web = ctx.Web;
                        ctx.Load(web);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                    }

                    possibleSites.Add(strSiteURL);
                    Console.WriteLine("URL: {0}", strSiteURL);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    string e = ex.Message;
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e);
                    continue;

                }
            }
            return possibleSites;
        }
}
```

Kindly assist to resolve the error.

Comment: Please post your code if you need help with your code.

Comment: On which line are you getting an error?

Comment: Error in `while ((iRead = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            objMemory.Write(buffer, 0, iRead);
                        } objMemory.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        ProcessFile(objMemory, file.Name, fileurl, file.TimeCreated, file.TimeLastModified, file.Length, "");`

Comment: The error in `file.Length`

Comment: The actual problem is with file.Length property. It site is SP 2013 it's working as expected. But in case of SP 2010 its not working due to file.Length property. Any way to get the file size?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason

The file.Length property is available only on SP 2013 site. When I tried to run my application on SP 2010 site I am getting the exception because the SP 2010 doesn't have  file.Length property

Refer:[File Properties - SharePoint 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file_properties(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: before giving a negative vote to the answer, how on green earth am i suppose to know you are using SharePoint 2010 and not SharePoint 2013. Try to post a detailed question. the negative vote doesn't encourage us to be active enough to help.

Answer (score -1):

First debug it and get to the line where the error is occurring. As far I see

the problem you are having is that your site path is not specified correctly.

Your FullUrl = @"http://servername/sites/xyz/default.aspx";
instead try

string FullUrl = @"http://servername/";

Comment: The problem is not with the site path. When I enterred "http://servername/sites/xyz/foldername" my application works as expected.

Comment: So now its working??

Comment: It's working as expected in my dev machine but not working in the server.

Comment: Check if the url is not of Dev machine one....The error is on URL part...there is no other error on logs

Comment: The URL is correct one. I can able to access the url. I have encountered the below exception  **Message:**  The property or field 'Length' has not been initialize
d. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
**stack trace:**    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject.Che
ckUninitializedProperty(String propName)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.get_Length()
   at ExScan_EDMS.Program.GetFoldersAndFiles(Folder mainFolder, ClientContext cl
ientContext)
**source:** Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime